# Generate new column based on two columns of dataframe

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas

I need to generate column `a_b` based on column `a` and column `b` of `df`, if both `a` and `b` are greater than 0, `a_b` is assigned a value of 1, if both `a` and `b` are less than 0, `a_b` is assigned a value of -1, I am using double `np.where` .

My code is as follows, where `generate_data` generates `demo data` and `get_result` is used for `production`, where `get_result` needs to be run 4 million times:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)


def generate_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    _df = pd.DataFrame(rand.uniform(-1, 1, 70).reshape(10, 7), columns=['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6'])
    return _df


def get_result(_df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    a = _df.a.to_numpy()
    for col in ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6']:
        b = _df[col].to_numpy()
        _df[f'a_{col}'] = np.where(
            (a > 0) & (b > 0), 1., np.where(
                (a < 0) & (b < 0), -1., 0.)
        )
    return _df


def main():
    df = generate_data()
    print(df)
    df = get_result(df)
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Data generated by generate_data:

```
          a        b1        b2        b3        b4        b5        b6
0  0.273923 -0.460427 -0.918053 -0.966945  0.626540  0.825511  0.213272
1  0.458993  0.087250  0.870145  0.631707 -0.994523  0.714809 -0.932829
2  0.459311 -0.648689  0.726358  0.082922 -0.400576 -0.154626 -0.943361
3 -0.751433  0.341249  0.294379  0.230770 -0.232645  0.994420  0.961671
4  0.371084  0.300919  0.376893 -0.222157 -0.729807  0.442977  0.050709
5 -0.379516 -0.028329  0.778976  0.868087 -0.284410  0.143060 -0.356261
6  0.188600 -0.324178 -0.216762  0.780549 -0.545685  0.246374 -0.831969
7  0.665288  0.574197 -0.521261  0.752968 -0.882864 -0.327766 -0.699441
8 -0.099321  0.592649 -0.538716 -0.895957 -0.190896 -0.602974 -0.818494
9  0.160665 -0.402608  0.343990 -0.600969  0.884226 -0.269780 -0.789009
```

My desired result:

```
          a        b1        b2        b3        b4        b5        b6  a_b1  \
0  0.273923 -0.460427 -0.918053 -0.966945  0.626540  0.825511  0.213272   0.0   
1  0.458993  0.087250  0.870145  0.631707 -0.994523  0.714809 -0.932829   1.0   
2  0.459311 -0.648689  0.726358  0.082922 -0.400576 -0.154626 -0.943361   0.0   
3 -0.751433  0.341249  0.294379  0.230770 -0.232645  0.994420  0.961671   0.0   
4  0.371084  0.300919  0.376893 -0.222157 -0.729807  0.442977  0.050709   1.0   
5 -0.379516 -0.028329  0.778976  0.868087 -0.284410  0.143060 -0.356261  -1.0   
6  0.188600 -0.324178 -0.216762  0.780549 -0.545685  0.246374 -0.831969   0.0   
7  0.665288  0.574197 -0.521261  0.752968 -0.882864 -0.327766 -0.699441   1.0   
8 -0.099321  0.592649 -0.538716 -0.895957 -0.190896 -0.602974 -0.818494   0.0   
9  0.160665 -0.402608  0.343990 -0.600969  0.884226 -0.269780 -0.789009   0.0   

   a_b2  a_b3  a_b4  a_b5  a_b6  
0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0  
1   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0  
2   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  
3   0.0   0.0  -1.0   0.0   0.0  
4   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0  
5   0.0   0.0  -1.0   0.0  -1.0  
6   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0  
7   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  
8  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0  
9   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
```

Performance evaluation:

```
%timeit get_result(df)
1.56 ms ± 54.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

How can it be faster?

Comment: Based on what you've shown, pandas is not needed here. Either you haven't shown code that's realistic enough, or my suggested changes are going to use pure Numpy.

Comment: @Reinderien My real code is exactly the same as the data generated by `generated_data`, just the column names are different.

Comment: I'm more talking about the way that the data are used before and after this segment of code in the program. I'll assume that pandas is not necessary.

Comment: @Reinderien You can see my other question, I need to process the `self.status` generated there, and the final result is `observastion`, and the type is `list`. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277147/

Comment: If you don't show the code you care about here, in this question, then for the purposes of review it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Reinderien My first question is yours. Based on your answer, I wrote the above question.   https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any value in Pandas here. Use Numpy broadcasting directly between an `a` 10x1 array and a `b` 10x6 array, producing a new 10x6 array. Your inner `where()` does work with these arrays unmodified, but there are faster methods that do not use `where` and instead call `np.sign` or `np.ceil`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np

rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
a = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10, 1))
b = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10, 6))

#  if both a and b are greater than 0, a_b is assigned a value of  1,
#  if both a and b are    less than 0, a_b is assigned a value of -1


def op():
    return np.where(
        (a > 0) & (b > 0),
        1,
        np.where(
            (a < 0) & (b < 0), -1, 0,
        )
    )


def ceils():
    return np.ceil(a)*np.ceil(b) - np.floor(a)*np.floor(b)


def signs():
    sa = np.sign(a)
    return sa * (sa == np.sign(b))


METHODS = (op, ceils, signs)

results = [method() for method in METHODS]
for result in results[1:]:
    assert np.allclose(results[0], result)

N = 10_000
times = defaultdict(list)
for _ in range(10):
    for method in METHODS:
        t = timeit(method, number=N)
        times[method.__name__].append(t)


for method, method_time in times.items():
    print(f'{method:>6}: {mean(method_time)/N*1e6:6.1f} us')
```

### Output

```
    op:   24.3 us
 ceils:   10.0 us
 signs:    8.0 us
```

Comment: Pure numpy signs() is 100 times faster than my code.